# Eigenvalues of a Block Matrix from Schur Determinant Identity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm recently playing with some $(n+k)\times (n+k)$ block matrices:
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{X} =
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{0}_{n\times n} & \mathbf{P}_{n\times k} \\
{\mathbf{P}}_{k\times n}^T & \mathbf{0}_{k\times k}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbf{P}_{n\times k}$ consists of $k$ orthonormal basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ so that $\mathbf{P}^T\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{I}_{k\times k}$. After playing with Matlab, I conjectured that $\mathbf{X}$ has a very special set of eigenvalues.
\begin{equation*}
\text{Eigenvalues of $\mathbf X$} =
\text{$k$ copies of -1, $k$ copies of +1, and $n-k$ copies of 0.}
\end{equation*}
There can be many ways to prove this, but I tried to compute [the characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) $p_{\mathbf{X}}(\lambda)$ of $\mathbf{X}$

\begin{equation*}
p_{\mathbf{X}}(\lambda) = \det(\lambda\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{X}) = \det
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda\mathbf{I}_n & -\mathbf{P} \\
-\mathbf{P}^T & \lambda\mathbf{I}_k
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

to show that $p_{\mathbf{X}}(\lambda) = (\lambda^2-1)^k\lambda^{n-k}$ which will prove my conjecture because the roots of a characteristic polynomial $p_{\mathbf{X}}(\lambda)$ are the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{X}$.

Maybe I can exploit [Schur determinant identity](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/matrix-identities-as-derivatives-of-determinant-identities/#schurd) which states that
\begin{equation*}
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{A} & \mathbf{B} \\ \mathbf{C} & \mathbf{D}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\det\mathbf{A}\cdot \det\left(
  \mathbf{D} - \mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{B}
\right)
\end{equation*}
assuming $\mathbf A$ is invertible.
Well, if I can assume $\lambda \neq 0$, then I can easily compute the characteristic polynomial using this identity.
\begin{align*}
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda\mathbf{I}_n & -\mathbf{P} \\
-\mathbf{P}^T & \lambda\mathbf{I}_k
\end{pmatrix}
&=
\det(\lambda\mathbf{I}_n)\cdot \det\left(
\lambda\mathbf{I}_k - \mathbf{P}^T(\lambda\mathbf{I}_n)^{-1}\mathbf{P}
\right)
\\
&=
\det(\lambda\mathbf{I}_n)\cdot\det
\left[\left(\lambda - \frac{1}{\lambda}\right)\mathbf{I}_k\right]
\\
&=
\lambda^n\left(\lambda - \frac{1}{\lambda}\right)^k
\\
&=
\lambda^{n-k}(\lambda^2 - 1)^k
\end{align*}

1. This *seems* the right answer but it only holds when $\lambda\neq 0$. How can I show that this *indeed* holds even when $\lambda = 0$? Maybe I can try the cofactor expansion for determinant but that seems not easy for this problem.
2. I once heard some people saying "the invertible matrices are dense in the space of all matrices, and we can conclude the general case holds as well by the continuity argument" in their papers but I cannot truly understand what they're saying. Can I just repeat what they said for my proof?
3. This is just an additional question but where can I find some explanation on such a *continuity argument*?

Comment: No continuity needed. If two polynomials with real coefficients are equal to each other at infinitely many points (e.g., at all nonzero reals, in your case), then they are identical. See http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/univid.pdf and http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/univid2.pdf for a thorough discussion of this tactic and similar ones.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: I'm not sure whether I can say *two* polynomials are equal to each other at infinitely many points. Which *two* polynomials do I have in this problem? I computed one characteristic polynomial assuming $\lambda\neq 0$, but what's the other?

Comment: The one polynomial is the characteristic polynomial; the other is $\lambda^{n-k}\left(\lambda^2-1\right)^k$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: I'm sorry but I still don't understand. You're saying that there's an way to evaluate $p_{\mathbf{X}}(\lambda) = \det\begin{pmatrix}\lambda\mathbf{I}_n & \mathbf{P} \\ \mathbf{P}^T & \lambda\mathbf{I}_k\end{pmatrix}$ and compare it to $\lambda^{n-k}(\lambda^2-1)^k$ to see whether these two are evaluated to the same value when $\lambda\neq 0$?

Comment: @user19906 Isn't that what you've done in your post above after words "Well, if I can assume $\lambda\ne 0$, then..."?

Comment: You have shown for two polynomials that $p(\lambda)=q(\lambda)$ for all $\lambda\ne 0$. It gives already more than enough to say that $p=q$. But if you do not trust it, you can easily check out what happens if $\lambda=0$. Clearly, $q(0)=0$ and $p(0)=\det(-X)=0$ since $X$ is singular. It gives $p(0)=q(0)$ which completes the proof. Note that some signs above are wrong ($P$ should be $-P$).